# Increment a value in XSLT

Tags: xslt, variables

I'm reasonably new to xlst and am confused as to whether there is any way to store a value and change it later, for example incrementing a variable in a loop.

I'm a bit baffled by not being able to change the value of a  after it's set doesn't make sense to me, making it more of a constant.

For example I want to do something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="i" select="0" />
<xsl:for-each select="data/posts/entry">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="$i + 1" />
    <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

If anyone can enlighten me on  whether there is an alternative way to do this
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, I didn't realise variables could be reused in a for-each loop. My problem was actually a lot more complicated than the example I posted and I found a solution using recursion, however I'll look into a more elegant solution using your suggestion

Comment: @Oliver While recursion is something universal, there are ways to replace recursion with iteration. This results in optimized -- both for time and space -- xslt applications.

Comment: They should have call it constant and not variable, the name is misleading.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**XSLT is a functional language** and among other things this means that variables **in XSLT are immutable** and once they have been defined their value cannot be changed.

**Here is how the same effect can be achieved in XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <posts>
    <xsl:for-each select="data/posts/entry">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="concat('$i = ', $i)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </posts>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<data>
 <posts>
  <entry/>
  <entry/>
  <entry/>
  <entry/>
  <entry/>
 </posts>
</data>
```

**the result is**:

```
<posts>
    <entry>$i = 1</entry>
    <entry>$i = 2</entry>
    <entry>$i = 3</entry>
    <entry>$i = 4</entry>
    <entry>$i = 5</entry>
</posts>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `position()` function:

- [Example 1](http://www.lib.tpu.ru/fulltext/m/2009/m4/XSLTreference/OutputOverview/function_position_frame.html)
- [Example 2](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_text.asp)

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/posts/entry">
  <xsl:text>
    Postion: '
  </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select = "position()" />
  <xsl:text>
    '
  </xsl:text>
  <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that myself two years ago. You need to do use recursion for this. I forget the exact syntax, but this site might help:

[Tip: Loop with recursion in XSLT](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tiploop.html)

The strategy works basically as follows: Replace `for` loop with a template "method". Have it recieve a parameter `i`. Do the body of the `for` loop in the template method. If `i > 0` call the template method again (recursion) with `i - 1` as parameter.

Pseudocode:

```
for i = 0 to 10:
   print i
```

becomes:

```
def printer(i):
   print i
   if i < 10:
      printer(i + 1)
printer(0)
```

Please note that using `position()` in a `xsl:for-each` (see other answers) can be simpler if all you want to do is have a variable increment. Use the kind of recursion explained here if you want a more complicated loop / condition.

Comment: The question was on XSL, but the answer is using Python? How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (IE specific) we can follow is to take help of Javascript using "msxsl:script"

```
<msxsl:script implements-prefix='yourprefix' language='JavaScript'>  
   <![CDATA[var counter=1; function getCounter(){return counter++;}]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Then we can call this method in our xsl

```
<xsl:value-of select="yourprefix:getCounter()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is if your Transformer supports Java extensions, you can call a static method to increment a variable that it holds internally.
Note that since this is a static method, you should maintain a Map of Sessions  and make sure your static method keeps a seperate tally for each Transformer instance:

```
  <xsl:variable name="sessionId" select="java:initXsltSession()"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

...

 <xsl:variable name="tally" select="java:getTally($sessionId, field[6])" />
```