# Explicitly Typed variables in XSL

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm using XSL's convenience functions for comparisons, `gt, lt, ge, le, eq`.

I understand these functions won't promote a string to a numerical value when performing comparisons, however I need that cast to be made, and I don't want to clutter my code with lines like

```
<xsl:when test="xs:integer($variable) lt 250" >
```

I'd rather make that cast like this (hypothetical of course)

```
<xsl:variable name="variable" type="xs:integer">
```

So, is there a means of explicitly casting `variable` as an numerical type when it is declared/created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:when test="xs:integer($variable) lt 250" >
> ```
>
> I'd rather make that cast like this (hypothetical of course)
>
> ```
> <xsl:variable name="variable" type="xs:integer">
> ```

**Use the `as` attribute** -- its purpose is exactly to specify the type of a variable, parameter, template or a function:

```
<xsl:variable name="variable" as="xs:integer" 
              select="some-integer-type-expression">
```

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev but does it initialize the variable with some default value? Say for example I am assigning this variable some value based on condition and if thats not satisfied in that case will it be initialized to 0?

Comment: @PaulPhoenix, There is no "default initialization" in XSLT -- because variables in XSLT cannot be changed -- they can have only the value they were given -- either with the `select` attribute, or inside their body, and this value can not be changed/re-assigned from this moment. XSLT is a functional programming language and variables are immutable.For more information how to "overcome" this immutability, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345640/36305

Comment: @PaulPhoenix, Try having: `    <xsl:variable name="vN" as="xs:integer"/>` in your code and also something that uses it as integer, for example: `<xsl:copy-of select="$vN + 3"/>` . You'll get a compile-time error like this (from Saxon 9.1J): "Error at xsl:variable on line 7 column 46 of yourfile.xsl:
  XTTE0570: The implicit value () is not valid for the declared type
Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected."