# XSL - increment a variable in <otherwise>

Tags: xslt

i'm currently facing an issue where i need to increment a variable based on a few checks:

I have the following code with the checks and calculations:

```
    <xsl:variable name="HBB_Nord_Counter" select="0" />

    <xsl:variable name="HBB_N_Check">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($MUC_HBB_Answered_N_WG_1 = '0') or ($MUC_HBB_SL_N_WG_1 = '0') or ($MUC_HBB_Entered_N_WG_1 = '0')">0</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="($MUC_HBB_Answered_N_WG_1 * number(translate($MUC_HBB_SL_N_WG_1, ',', '.'))) div ($MUC_HBB_Entered_N_WG_1)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

and I have build an if statement where my variable is incremented based on the above mentioned:

```
<xsl:variable name="HBB_Nord_Counter_2" >
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$HBB_N_Check &gt; 0">
            <xsl:value-of select="$HBB_Nord_Counter + 1" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$HBB_Nord_Counter" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now the question:

How can i include the second portion of the code in the first part of the code, so that my variable: *HBB_Nord_Counter* is incremented by one if the conditions in the second code are met.

I need this variable to divide a sum against it, depending on how many values are greater than 0.

I hope this is understandable enough.

Best regards,
Ionut Sanda

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment a value in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344965/increment-a-value-in-xslt)

Comment: As the link in the previous comment explains, variables cannot be incremented in XSLT 1.0. It might be better to reframe your question to explain the problem you are trying to solve, as it might be you don't need to use variables at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have found the question that you are referring to, but it didn't help me. Thanks.

Comment: You should tell us what problem you are trying to solve (what the input and output of the transformation are). Saying that you need to do it by incrementing variables isn't helpful, that's like saying you need to do it by squaring the circle. If you tell us what your input and output are, we can show you how to do it without mutable variables.

Answer (score 0):

In other programming languages variables are *true* variables, i.e. you can:

- initially assign a value to them,
- then you can change this value (as many times as you wish).

In **XSLT** the situation is diffrent: What we call *variables* are actually
*constants*. You assign a value on creation of a variable and then you
**cannot** change it.

Maybe you should count source elements meeting particular condition?
Something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="cnt" select="count(tagname[condition]"/>
```

substituting proper tag name and a condition in the predicate.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, but unfortunately I can't find the exact position, nor the *tagname*, nor the condition i must enter in the above statement so that it works as required. So I guess other than the If I created in the code, there is no other way to increment a variable in xslt?

Comment: Actually, variables in functional programming languages correspond closely to variables in mathematics, whereas variables in procedural programming languages are completely different. So I would quarrel with your use of "true variables" here.

Comment: I did some research, and found that I can somehow split my file into two pieces, so I did. I have a file which contains all my variables, and one file that contains my whole html part. I did create a file called bmw.xsl which contains all my variables, and at the end of the file I wrote <xsl:include href=main.xsl">. This main.xsl is the file which has all my html part. When i'm trying to upload this, I do receive an error: "Execute failed: XSLT compile error".